# Core data fetch request with predicate. Need right NSPredicate

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsdate, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I got entity with two **NSDate properties**. They are here: `startTime, endTime` and two restrictions, they are here too: `NSDate *begin, NSDate *end`

**But the problem is endTime can be nil**

I need to fetch all entities which:

```
(entity.startTime >= begin) AND (entity.endTyme == nil)
```

if (endType == nil)

and

```
(entity.startTime >= begin) AND (entity.endTyme <= end)
```

if (endTyme != nil)

How to make union from those two fetch predicates? Or maybe use filter?

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: If i did fetch without predicate, i get all entities from database, if i use this predicate, i get only first entities. First = entity with early startTime

Comment: The predicate seems to be OK. Can you show the output of `NSLog(@"predicate = %@", predicate)` ?

Comment: Have you logged the `begin` and `end` dates and the dates of each of the objects? Can you show that?

Comment: I did not see any mistakes

Comment: NSLog (@"predicate = %@",predicate)
predicate = startTime >= CAST(371836140.000000, "NSDate") AND endTime <= CAST(466444140.000000, "NSDate")

Comment: I can't see that exactly from your code : Is a *new* fetched results controller created when the begin/end date changes?

Comment: Is not. I did roll NSDatePicker in child view controller, then press button to save and go to parent view controller, and then parent view controller did new fetch with same FRC.

Comment: @OlegSobolev: So could that be the problem? If the same FRC is used, the search predicate has not changed to the new dates.

Comment: I use NSUserDefaults in FRC to get fresh _begin_ and _end_ dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*Remark:* You have edited your question heavily several times. I would be better to *append*
new information about your problem, otherwise comments and answers are difficult to 
understand for future readers.)

To fetch all objects where the start time is >= a given time, and the end time is `nil` *or*
<= a given time, you can use the predicate

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(startTime >= %@) AND (endTime == nil OR endTime <= %@)",
       startTime, endTime]
```

Comment: look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363500/core-data-fetch-predicate-for-nsdate

Answer (score 1):

Your setup and predicate are correct. Check your data and you will discover that the predicate works as expected.

Comment: I agree, everything looks fine. The problem is most likely in actual data

Comment: Make a NSLog statement that shows both the begin and end dates as well as the dates of the entity. Then compare.

Comment: When i do roll NSDatePicker - two NSDate are have difference. But when i press "save" button - i got same date in both NSDate variables.

Comment: Bingo! - You found your error. As you see, it nothing to do with the predicate. Please accept the answer.